# Django conditionally excluding fields

Tags: python, django, orm

I am new to Django and am having some trouble with filtering.  Please excuse the contrived example.  I have some model for events, with a one to many relationship with attendees.  From my set of events I want to exclude events occurring in Boston, but only if there's only 1 attendee.  The code below is what I've tried that definitely does not work:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(attendees_count=Count('attendees')).exclude(attendees_count=1, event_location__city="Boston")
```

I don't get an error.  Rather it just filters out "Boston" regardless of "attendees_count".

In addition to a query that actually does what I want it to do, I'd like to understand why what I did doesn't work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Where is `queryset` coming from?

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting the attribute `attendees` with your annotation. Try `annotate(attendees_count=Count('attendees')).exclude(attendees=1)`

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony - I think you mean `.exclude(attendees_count=1)`.

Comment: Hi sorry i just slapped together an analagous example.  Also I am not getting an error, rather it's filtering out "Boston" regardless of attendees count

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your original queryset includes Boston with >1 attendee?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude

> Multiple parameters are joined via AND in the underlying SQL
>   statement, and the whole thing is enclosed in a NOT()